# PHP hindii encoding issue

Tags: php, wordpress, powerpoint, encode

My custom WordPress plugin getting post content from the database which is in the Hindi language. I am generating a text file like this:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-16le");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $file_base .'-'. $post_date .'.txt"');

echo $text;
```

When I imported the text file to PowerPoint 2007 it is showing like this:

[image]

But if I open the text file using Windows Text Editor and then save on UTF-16LE format. Then PowerPoint reading it correctly.

I have spent a day searching for the solution but failed. What might be the issue?

Comment: Is your content actually stored in UTF-16LE in your MySQL database?

Comment: @Dai I am not really sure. I think it must me UTF-8 because it is WordPress default.

Comment: Is the font in PowerPoint set to one that includes Hindi characters? As a test,  try Arial Unicode if you have it installed.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I don't think this is a font issue - Windows (and Office) will use fallback fonts and characters, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/input/font-technology#font-fallback - Given that MySQL defaults to `latin1` and that PHP passes bytes in strings verbatim, and the OP's script is asserting it's UTF-16LE then that's my theory.

Comment: @G'ofurN Why are you opening a text file in PowerPoint instead of Notepad? Wnd why are you using UTF-16LE as a header value when you haven't posted any PHP code that shows you actually using UTF-16LE? As you said, WordPress uses UTF-8 (and MySQL uses `latin1` by default), so there's at least 3 things you need to investigate - and no-one should be using UTF-16 thesedays anyway.

Comment: @Dai in short I don't mind printing in UTF-8 encode and previously I printed in UTF-8 ecnode too. But my client said his PowerPoint reading UTF-16LE Hindi characters correctly. But, then, when I tried generating UTF-16LE his PowerPoint is not reading Hindi characters correctly. But if I print english characters in UTF-8 and UTF-16LE  his PowerPoint reading English characters correctly and directly

Comment: @Dai That makes sense. Thanks.